# Add a specific element after loop

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm generating a paragraph.
I want to add `<ul>` under the 3rd paragraph.

Here is the code snippet:

```js
var i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  const para = document.createElement("p");
  const node = document.createTextNode("This is new.");
  para.appendChild(node);
  const element = document.getElementById("div1");
  element.appendChild(para);
  // add ul under the 3rd paragraph
}
```

```css
.nav {
  background-color: grey;
  text-align: center;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition: background .5s;
  /* .5s how long transition should take */
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <p>Test</p>
</ul>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: When `i` is 2, append the ul to `div1`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to inject the ul under your 3rd paragraph in the element with id1?
You can have something like:

```
// On your "add ul under the 3rd paragraph line

 if (i == 2){ //Condition for 3rd paragraph (-1 as the loop starts on 0)
 
const menu = document.getElementsByClassName("nav")[0]; //get the ul you want to add. getElementsByClassName returns a list, so would need to get the item you want to add. You might want to use an id in case you have multiple elements with class nav.

//Finally, add the element on your div1
document.getElementById("div1").appendChild(menu); 

}
```

Comment: If `i == 3`, then you're on the 4th paragraph since `i` starts at 0